# Error "Cannot access 'client' before initialization" while trying to make command handling

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I was trying to add a command handler (or a command folder)

I haven't tried to add commands inside the folder, but everytime I try to run the code, it says:

"Cannot access 'client' before initialization"

I get the error itself, but I don't know what to do about it.
It might refer to adding the code too early, but I have tried multiple times.

The Full index.js file is here:

```
const { REST, Routes, Collection } = require('discord.js');
const Token = process.env.TOKEN
const ClientID = process.env.CLIENT_ID
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');

require('dotenv').config();
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));


for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    // Set a new item in the Collection with the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
    if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
        client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    } else {
        console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
    }
}

client.commands = new Collection();


const commands = [
  {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Get the latency/ping of the bot.',
  },
];

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);

(async () => {
  try {

    console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

    await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(process.env.CLIENT_ID), { body: commands });

    console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();


const express = require("express");
const app = express()
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Candy is running, Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  client.user.setPresence({
        status: "online",  //You can show online, idle....
        activity: {
            name: "Using slash commands",  //The message shown
            type: "LISTENING" //PLAYING: WATCHING: LISTENING: STREAMING:
        }
    });
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

  if (interaction.comsmandName === 'ping') {
    const ping = await interaction.reply({ content: 'Pinging...', fetchReply: true });
    interaction.editReply(`Roundtrip latency: ${ping.createdTimestamp - interaction.createdTimestamp}ms`);
  }
});

 
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

I first tried to rearrange "client.commands = new Collection();" after the:

```
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
```

It still had the same error, so I putted it more to the bottom, but it still didn't work.

So, I tried to move the commands folder inside the **source/src** folder. But it still printed out the error.

Comment: What this error means is that you'll need to put the `const client = new Client` line before you use it in the `client.commands` line

Comment: I tried to do it. the const Client = new client was already there, so I moved it but it still printed out the error.

Comment: I included [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] intents also. my mistake for not mentioning that. but if it's still wrong, then specify what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Cannot access 'client' before initialization"

The error tells that the `client` you are trying to access (in the first `if` *block*: `initialize.js:25`) should be initialised before in other words, move the lines along with the required imports before that `if` block:

```js
//..

const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const express = require("express");

// ..

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.commands = new Collection();


//..rest of the code
```

*Note:* the code is omitted for brevity

**Edit:** To prevent this systematically, you might want to use [Eslint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp05J.png) specifically [`no-use-before-define`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-use-before-define). This works best in combination with Editors like VSCode along with the [Eslint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint):

[image: Extension Result Highlight]

---